# Update value of nested array in firebase database

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I'm building a web app with Vue.js using Firebase authentication and real time database, which I'm new to. 
In this app the user answers to questions to achieve some points.

**My problem is**: I want to update an existing array already stored and created in the database so that the `progress/points` of that user will be under track to update all the components in my app.

For example let's say I want to increase `+1` the highlighted value in the screenshot:

[image: nested array]

I was thinking about something like `userid.progress[6][0] += 1` like in normal javascript, but I can't update the database, value still at `0`.
I've read something about `.set()` or `.update()` but in that case I should rewrite all the array (and it would be a problem), but I might be completely wrong.

PS: it's not a problem about getting the user id or the current user, everything is working fine.
Hope to find someone to help me, thank you so much in advance!

Comment: you cant do like that. first `get()` the value stored, the use `.update()` to increment

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to accomplish, but I wrote an answer for a few likely problems below. Next time please include the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it takes much of the guess work out of answering and drastically improves your chances of getting good help quickly.

Comment: I would go with @FrankvanPuffelen answer on this. But in general [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). They are very difficult to work with as adding or removing elements requires the array to be read and re-written. Additionally, they are not directly queryable. They really don't integrate into JSON structures and there are usually much better options. If you can update your question with a specific use case (like what does 0, 1, 2, 3 represents) and perhaps some code, we can probably provide a more complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to update an existing score, you can write on the most granular level. So:

```
ref.child("pjoCy...0tl3/progress/0/6/0").set(1)
```

If you want to push a new score to the end of the array, you'll indeed need to read the entire score array to add a new value to the end. This is one of the many reasons why Firebase recommends against using array indices like you do. If you instead us so-called push-IDs, adding a new value becomes as easy as:

```
ref.child("pjoCy...0tl3/progress/0/6").push(1)
```

I recommend reading more about [structuring lists in the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data) and the classic blog posts on [handling arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).